# spark java how to process rdd by key

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I’m just getting started with both Hadoop and Spark.  I’ve run into what I assume is a simple problem but I can’t seem to determine the best way forward!  I'm using Spark 1.2.1 since this is what is currently supported by Hortonworks which we are using.
I have data in Hive that I’m analysing with the mlib KMeans clustering algorithm implementation.

My data is naturally grouped by key, and I am doing my clustering analysis by this key.
For Kmeans, I require a JavaRDD of the data points by key.

My issue is that the only way I’ve managed to create this JavaRDD of data points is to do a mapToPair and GroupByKey on my source data in a JavaSchemaRDD, then loop over the keys, though I don’t think this is the optimal approach. 
I guess what I need is a way to process my data and create the JavaRDD of data points by key.

Sample code snippet:

```
// get the source data to cluster out of the database:
JavaSchemaRDD sqlData = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM "+sourceDBName+"."+sourceTableName);

// grouped by key:
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Row>> groupedByKey = sqlData.mapToPair(new PairByKey()).groupByKey();

// Loop over all keys:
for (String key : groupedByKey.keys().collect())
{
    // Filter for this Key:
    JavaSchemaRDD keyData = sqlData.filter(new FilterByKey(key));

    // Duration vs Score for this TP:
    JavaRDD<Vector> lengthVsScore = keyData.map(new GetLengthVsScore());
    lengthVsScore.cache();

    // Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
    KMeansModel clusters = KMeans.train(lengthVsScore.rdd(), 2, 20);
}
```

The hadoop table is created using a CSV file having four columns, data type in square brackets:
actor[STRING],key[STRING],x[INT],y[INT]
'key' is the value value that I want to group by, x and y are the numerical values that we wish to cluster on.

Is there a better way to do this?  Avoid the for loop and groupedByKey.keys().collect()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out the map functions. I am not familiar with them in Java, but this type of problem is why I started using Scala instead.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the format of a row in your `sqlData`? Maybe the implementation of the `PairByKey` function would help as well.

Comment: Hi vanekjar, I've updated the post to provide info about he row format.

Comment: I will try to use the map function on the JavaPairRDD, groupedByTP in my code snippet, but it seems odd that the call method of the function receives an iterable of the full data set per key in the K,V pair.  Would this be "distributed" still, or would the full collection of values need to fit within memory in one node for this to work?  It just looked add that it wasn't an RDD... thought I need to turn it back into an RDD for the mllib.clustering.KMeans implementation.